# rails - how to target nested controller for nested resource route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my `routes.rb` I have

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :clients do, only: [:index] do
    resources :products, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  end

  resources :products, only: [:index]
end
```

Notice that I have two lines for `resources :products`. One is nested within `resources :clients` and the other as a top-level resource on `:admin`; each of these two has a different purpose in the application.

`rake routes` gives me:

```
           admin_clients GET  /admin/clients(.:format)                         admin/clients#index
   admin_client_products GET  /admin/clients/:client_id/products(.:format)     admin/products#index
                         POST /admin/clients/:client_id/products(.:format)     admin/products#create
new_admin_client_product GET  /admin/clients/:client_id/products/new(.:format) admin/products#new
          admin_products GET  /admin/products(.:format)                        admin/products#index
```

I have a `admin_client_products` for the nested `product#index` resource. I also have `admin_products` for the top-level `product#index` resource. However, they point to the same controller action: `admin/product#index`.

Question: At this point, I need rails to deduce that these are two different actions. Using rails conventions, is there a way to tell rails that these two resources should have different controller actions i.e. one that should hit `admin/products#index` and the other should hit `admin/clients/products#index`?

The nested route should hit this:

```
class Admin::Clients::ProductsController < Admin::BaseController      
  def index; end
end
```

The top-level route should hit this:

```
class Admin::ProductsController < Admin::BaseController      
  def index; end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely you can!

Here you need to customize your resourceful route by explicitly specifying a controller to use for the resource. The `:controller` option will let you do that.

So, in your case, specifying the controller as `clients/products` for the `admin_clients_products` resource would work in your desired way.

```ruby
namespace :admin do
  resources :clients, only: [:index] do
    resources :products, only: [:index, :new, :create], controller: 'clients/products'
  end                                                 # ------------------------------

  resources :products, only: [:index]
end
```

`rails routes` will now give you what you want:

```ruby
admin_client_products    GET /admin/clients/:client_id/products(.:format)   admin/clients/products#index
                         POST   /admin/clients/:client_id/products(.:format)     admin/clients/products#create
new_admin_client_product GET    /admin/clients/:client_id/products/new(.:format) admin/clients/products#new
admin_clients            GET    /admin/clients(.:format)                         admin/clients#index
admin_products           GET    /admin/products(.:format)                        admin/products#index
```

=========================

Extra bits:

If you want to omit the `/admin` portion from the url (I mean, if your application's routing design permits to), then you could use:

```
scope module: 'admin' do...end
```

like the following:

```ruby
scope module: 'admin' do
  resources :clients, only: [:index] do
    resources :products, only: [:index, :new, :create], controller: 'clients/products'
  end

  resources :products, only: [:index]
end
```

and suddenly your routes will start looking awesome :)

```ruby
client_products     GET    /clients/:client_id/products(.:format)     admin/clients/products#index
                    POST   /clients/:client_id/products(.:format)     admin/clients/products#create
new_client_product  GET    /clients/:client_id/products/new(.:format) admin/clients/products#new
clients             GET    /clients(.:format)    admin/clients#index
products            GET    /products(.:format)  admin/products#index
```